# JPA insert fails after 400 (or so) inserts - transaction error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jboss7.x

Update: It seems it's failing after one insert, #412, fails a not null constraint at the database level.  The transaction is probably rolling itself back.  Given this setup, is it possible to get a new transaction established?

I'm trying to insert a lot of rows into my oracle database, and JPA works just fine until about the 400th insert.  I expect to have several thousand rows to insert.

Here's my psuedo-code (shortened for clarity) & persistence.xml:

```
@Stateless
public class LocalContentService
{
    @Inject EntityManager em;

    public void mySavingMethod(){
        for(Foo foo : fooDao.fetchAllFoos()){
            Bar bar = new Bar(foo);

            em.persist(bar);
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
            log.debug("Saved content for: " + bar.getId());
        }
    }


<persistence-unit name="databaseTest" >
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/testDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <class>org.myorg.Bar</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

After roughly 400 rows, I get this error message and all subsequent inserts fail:

> ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469:
>   Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a
>   transaction or extended persistence context)

So my question is two fold

1) What on earth happened to my transaction midway through the process? Can it be avoided?

2) Is there a better approach to doing a bulk insert like this one (keeping in mind that i'm loading a bunch of Foo's and they need to be transformed into Bar's before persisting.

I'm running inside a jBoss 7.1.1.Final AS and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api

Comment: Why are you flushing and clearing the entity manager with each transaction. That forces a sync with the database. Not saying thats why your transaction is failing, but it will make your method ***very*** slow.

Comment: that's good feedback... i'll make this update. like you say, i'm not sure it will solve the problem.

Comment: If it's a non-null constraint that makes the transaction rollback, fix the bug: make sure not to insert null into this column or, if null values are acceptable, remove the non-null constraint.

Comment: As I see it, part of the bug is that constraint violations are not reported, which would be a severe flaw in exception handling that makes debugging needlessly hard. Regardless of that particular constraint violation, such poor exception handling is worth improving.